# Kendo-grid in Angular 6: isEditing: how?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to get whether or not the Kendo-grid is in its "editing stage". I found [this documentation which tells me that it's possible](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-isediting), however I can't seem to find out how to use that. It's not possible to use like this:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" (isEditing)="isEditing($event)"> (...) </kendo-grid>
```

That way, the function never gets called.
I'm probably not completely awake yet. Could someone give me a hand? Do I need to get an instance of the `kendo-grid` and run a function on that instance? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isEditing` is a method on the grid component not an event.

So basically you need to have a reference to your grid and then you can call the method for example in the toolbar template to show some text:

```
   <kendo-grid
       #grid
       [data]="gridData">
       <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
            <span *ngIf="grid.isEditing()">A row is being edited</span>
       </ng-template>

       <kendo-grid-column
           field="UnitPrice"
           title="Unit Price"
           [width]="180"
           format="{0:c}">
       </kendo-grid-column>

       <kendo-grid-column
           field="Discontinued"
           title="Discontinued"
           [width]="100">
       </kendo-grid-column>
   </kendo-grid>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Did not know how to get a reference.